# How to override Hibernate Id generation for strategy GenerationType.TABLE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I need to override the values that are generated from Hibernate for an entity when the selected strategy is `GenerationType.TABLE`.

One example of needing to override the generated value is when a value for the id field is already supplied by some other layer of the application, I don't want Hibernate to generate a new value, but instead use the supplied one.

Here is the id part of the entity (AdvEntity)

```
@TableGenerator(name = "AID_SERIAL",
                table = "serial",
                pkColumnName="name", pkColumnValue = "adv",
                valueColumnName = "no", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE, generator="AID_SERIAL")
@Column(name = "AID")
@Id
public Integer getAid() {
    return aid;
}
```

I have found many answers that describe how to solve the problem when `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` is used, but couldn't locate any for `GenerationType.TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the code in Hibernate with the debugger I came up with the following code that solved my problem:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "AID_SERIAL", strategy = "my.package.structure.AdvAidValueGenerator",
                  parameters = {
                                    @Parameter(name="table", value="serial"),
                                    @Parameter(name="primary_key_column", value="name"),
                                    @Parameter(name="max_lo", value="0"),
                                    @Parameter(name="table", value="serial"),
                                    @Parameter(name="value_column", value="no"),
                                    @Parameter(name="primary_key_value", value="adv")
                  })
@GeneratedValue(generator="AID_SERIAL")
@Column(name = "AID")
@Id
public Integer getAid() {


   return aid;
}



public class AdvAidValueGenerator extends MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator {

        @Override
        public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
            if(!(object instanceof AdvEntity)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("AdvAidValueGenerator should only be used for AdvEntity");
            }

            final AdvEntity advEntity = (AdvEntity) object;
            final Integer presentAid = advEntity.getAid();
            if(null == presentAid) {
                return super.generate(session, object);
            }
            return presentAid;
        }
}
```

Note that this strategy is Hibernate specific and will not work for other JPA vendors

I should also add that I was using Hibernate version 4.3.1

Comment: I answered my own question as is allowed (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) in order to help future readers that could possibly have the same problem